# Data strings from other dataframe removal

Tags: r

From a dataframe with a string

```
 df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("Here is my text", "another effort of my text", "final effort of my text"))
```

And having a second dataframe with other words:

```
df2 <- data.frame(col2 = c("my", "text"))
```

How is it possible to remove the words from df1 which are in df2?
What to be expect:

```
data.frame(col1 = c("Here is ", "another effort of ", "final effort of "))
```

Comment: Why is it necessary that these words be in a different `data.frame`? Are these two `data.frame` objects the same length?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `vapply`

```
words_remove <- as.character(.subset2(df2,1L))
strings <- strsplit(as.character(.subset2(df1,1L)),' ')
data.frame(col1 = vapply(seq_along(strings),
       function (k) {
        current_words <- strings[[k]]
        paste(current_words[!(current_words %in% words_remove)], collapse = ' ')
       }, character(1))
)
#                col1
# 1           Here is
# 2 another effort of
# 3   final effort of
```

Note that the white spaces at then end of are *not* kept - if needed that can be implemented though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
library(tidyverse)
    df1 %>% 
      mutate(col1=str_remove_all(df1$col,"my text"))
```

Comment: it is necessary because the specific df contains more words

Comment: @nate 's answer seems more efficient.